# The Importance Of Equivalences

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

Okay, I asked a question earlier today, [Congruence Class $[n]_5$ (Equivalence class of n wrt congruence mod 5) when n = $-3$, 2, 3, 6](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234282/congruence-class#234291), pertaining to finding equivalence classes. I already know how to solve such problems, now my question is, what is the importance of having/knowing what an equivalence class is? Does it reveal any sort of information about the relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In *nice* algebraic structures (as groups, rings, modules, Boolean algebras, etc), one congruence class determines the whole congruence relation.

Considering the quotient by an equivalence (or congruence) relation is the counterpart of *division* of integer numbers.