# Describing Equivalence Classes using set builder notation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

How would you describe all the equivalence classes for the relation: $congruence$ $modulo$ $5$ over $Z$, using set builder notation?

Comment: Is that it? I thought it was too obvious to be right. I was trying to think of a 'formula' to use in set builder notation.

Guess I'm just over complicating it.

Comment: This may also help:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234282/congruence-class-n-5-equivalence-class-of-n-wrt-congruence-mod-5-when-n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the equivalence classes must be subsets of $\Bbb Z$.  Using set-builder notation, the equivalence classes are
$$S_a=\{\,a+5k\mid k\in{\Bbb Z}\,\}$$
for $a=0,1,2,3,4$.

Answer (score 2):

These will be expressions for the *set* of equivalence classes; each equivalence class will be an element of the set.

Using set builder notation *twice*: $\big\{\ \{n + 5m: m \in \mathbb{Z} \} : n \in \mathbb{Z} \ \big\}$, or more economically, $\big\{\ \{n + 5m: m \in \mathbb{Z} \} : n = 0,1,2,3,4 \ \big\}$

Using it just once: $\{ n + 5\mathbb{Z} : n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$, or
more economically, $\{n + 5\mathbb{Z} : n = 0,1,2,3,4 \}$.

Most economically (and definitionally): $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalence classes of $\mathbb{Z}_5$ will be given by it's elements.

Here: $\mathbb{Z}_5=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$

Thus, you can read off the equivalence classes of $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

$\bf{Additional}$: Yes, for each class to obtain elements in that specific class you begin with the element which names the class and add any multiple of your modulus.

Comment: Would the equivalence class $[2]$ simply be $\{0,2\}$?

Comment: The equivalence class of $2$ will be all $X$ such that $X=2+5K$ for all integers $K$.

Comment: The equivalence class [2] is $\{\ldots, -8, -3, 2, 7, 12, 17, \ldots\} = \{2 + 5k : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

Comment: Thus, $\mathbb{Z}_5\ne\{0,1,2,3,4\}$, for example $0\notin\mathbb{Z}_5$ but $5\mathbb Z\in\mathbb Z_5$.