# equivalence classes of $x^2 \equiv y^2 \pmod{7}$ for all integers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

How do I denote the equivalence classes for $x^2 \equiv y^2 \pmod{7}$ for all integers.
I know the possible results are $0, 1, 2$ and $4$.

$$x\equiv0 \pmod{7}, \space x^2\equiv0^2  \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$$
$$x\equiv1 \pmod{7}, \space x^2\equiv1^2  \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$$
$$x\equiv2 \pmod{7}, \space x^2\equiv2^2  \equiv 4 \pmod{7}$$
$$x\equiv3 \pmod{7}, \space x^2\equiv3^2  \equiv 2 \pmod{7}$$

But I do not understand how to denote it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalence class of an element $x$ is denoted by $[x]$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class

So you should write like this:
$$[0]=\{y\in\mathbb{Z}\colon 7\mid y^2\}=\{y\in\mathbb{Z}\colon 7\mid y\}=\{7k\colon k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$
$$[1]=\{y\in\mathbb{Z}\colon 7\mid y^2-1\}=\{7k\pm 1\colon k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$
etc. (of course it suffices to write it for 0,1,2,3,4,5,6, because $[x+7n]=[x]$ for any $x,n\in\mathbb{Z}$)

You can use shorter notation for these sets: $7\mathbb{Z}$, $7\mathbb{Z}\pm 1$ etc. where $AB=\{ab\colon a\in A, b\in B\}$.

---

Here is a similar topic:
[Congruence Class $[n]_5$ (Equivalence class of n wrt congruence mod 5) when n = $-3$, 2, 3, 6](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234282/congruence-class-n-5-equivalence-class-of-n-wrt-congruence-mod-5-when-n?rq=1)

Comment: So the equivalence classes would then be?  

[0]={y∈Z:7∣y^2}={y∈Z:7∣y}={7k:k∈Z}  
[1]={y∈Z:7∣y^2-1}={7k±1:k∈Z}  
[2]={y∈Z:7∣y^2-3}={7k±3:k∈Z}  
[4]={y∈Z:7∣y^2-2}={7k±2:k∈Z}  

Sorry for the terrible formatting.